# Jquery Validation showing single error infront of City/Zip on a single row

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have City & Zip inputboxes on a single row and there required error is shown infront of them in a TD.
Problem is that on error I see 2 required errors which you can see in the below HTML taken in Firebug.

What I want to do is show single error for both City/Zip infront of them.

**How to check that City/Zip has already error added in TD infront of them?**

***FireFox FireBug***

```
<tr>
    <td class="normalformCaptionTd">* City :</td>
    <td class="normalformFieldTd">
        <input id="City" class="normalformFieldCity error" type="text" tabindex="3" name="City">
        <span class="normalformBold">* Zip :</span>
        <input id="Zip" class="normalformFieldCity zip error" type="text" tabindex="4" name="Zip">
    </td>
    <td class="msgMiddle">
        <em class="error" for="City" generated="true">Required</em>
        <em class="error" for="Zip" generated="true">Required</em>
    </td>
</tr>


    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

             if (element.attr("name") == "City" || element.attr("name") == "Zip" )
                //How to check that City/Zip has already error added in TD infront of them?
             else
                error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );

            },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `element()` method of the `validator` object to check if a field is valid.
Like this:

```
var validator = $("#your_form").data('validator');
if(validator.element($("#City"))){ //Check if #City is valid
   ...
}
if(validator.element($("#Zip"))){ //Check if #City is valid
   ...
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Villegas Alvarado , I am still confused. Tried not working. Can you please add more logic into you code please.